# Produce mapfile with CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS and MSVC14

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, clion

I'am trying to generate a Mapfile with CMake (Clion)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(cmake_testapp)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
MESSAGE("TEST_HELLO")
set(MSVC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "/Fm${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/file.map")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${MSVC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}" )
MESSAGE(${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})
MESSAGE(${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER})
add_executable(cmake_testapp loaderstack.cpp)
```

Output:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2020.1.1\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles" C:\Users\remi\Desktop\OK
TEST_HELLO
/FmC:/Users/remi/Desktop/OK/file.map /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/remi/Desktop/OK/cmake-build-debug

[Finished]
```

But no file.map is produced even if the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` contains the flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map file is generated by the linker, and is typically *disabled by default*. To enable generation of a map file, the [`/MAP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/map-generate-mapfile?view=vs-2019) linker option must be provided. When I tested with `/MAP`, the compiler flag `/Fm` specifying the map file path name was ignored, and the map file was generated with a default name next to the binary.

However, you can also specify the map file name by appending it to the `/MAP` linker option. In CMake, you can specify link options for a specific target using [`target_link_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_options.html):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(cmake_testapp)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
MESSAGE("TEST_HELLO")

MESSAGE(${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER})
add_executable(cmake_testapp loaderstack.cpp)

# Set the coverage flags for the cmake_testapp executable only.
target_link_options(cmake_testapp PRIVATE "/MAP:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/file.map")
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting it works. Now i'am trying to get a MAP file for g++ MinGw64. And I absolutely don't get it :
set(CMAKE_CXX_LINKER_WRAPPER_FLAG "-Xlinker -Map=output.map")
set(CMAKE_CXX_LINKER_WRAPPER_FLAG_SEP "-Map=output.map")

Don't works.

target_link_options(cmake_testapp PRIVATE "-Xlinker -Map=output.map")

Don't Work too

target_link_options(cmake_testapp PRIVATE "-Map")

Don't work

target_link_options(cmake_testapp PRIVATE "/MAP")

Don't work. 

And I don't find easy answer for this on google. Is-it so exotic to ask for a mapfile ? 

Thanks again for all.

Comment: It works for : set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Xlinker -Map=output.map" )

Comment: @MelectronVolt Generating a map file will likely require different options for each different compiler. Your question post was specific to the VisualC++ compiler. I'm not as familiar with the MinGW options for generating map files.

Comment: Yes but how to know that Visual C++ need target_link_options /MAP ? It's /Fm in the documentation. Where do you find this information so I could find myself next time ?

Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @MelectronVolt I just took a look at the Microsoft VisualC++ [compiler options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options-listed-alphabetically?view=vs-2019), specifically the `/Fm` option. The documentation for `/Fm` mentioned `/MAP` (linked in my response) which could accomplish the same map file generation.